# From a list of emails, how to find with the Firebase Admin SDK the ones that belong to existing users in the Auth Service?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have an array of emails and I want, with the Admin SDK (for example in a Cloud Function), to find which emails belong to users in the Firebase Auth Service.

I know that we can use the [`getUserByEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#node.js_1) method of the Admin SDK to fetch the profile information of **ONE** user. With this method, if the provided email does not belong to an existing user in the Auth Service it will return an error with code `auth/user-not-found`.

If I use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and pass it the array of emails to execute the asynchronous `getUserByEmail()` method for each email in parallel, it doesn't work: As a matter of fact, as soon as one of the email is not belonging to a user, the corresponding Promise is rejected and `Promise.all()` **rejects immediately** and we miss the check for the rest of the emails array.

I also know that I can [list all the users existing in the Auth Service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) but this not efficient in my case.

So, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) method. As detailed in the method documentation:

> The promise returned by `Promise.allSettled()` will wait for all input
> promises to complete, **regardless of whether or not one rejects**.
>
> The fulfillment value of `Promise.allSettled()` is an array of
> objects, each describing the outcome of one promise in the iterable
> (our emails Array), in the order of the promises passed, regardless of
> completion order.
>
> Each outcome object has the following properties:
>
> - status: A string, either "fulfilled" or "rejected", indicating the eventual state of the promise.
> - value: Only present if status is "fulfilled". The value that the promise was fulfilled with.
> - reason: Only present if status is "rejected". The reason that the promise was rejected with.

Therefore the following code will do the trick:

```
const usersEmails = ['john@gmail.com', 'jack@gmail.com', 'jen@gmail.com'];  // Array of emails, e.g 

const promises = [];
usersEmails.forEach(email => {
       promises.push(admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email));
});

const fetchAuthServiceResults = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

const emailsInAuthService = fetchAuthServiceResults.filter(promise => promise.status === 'fulfilled').map(promise => promise.value.email);
```